# How to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, http

i have this simple HTML which calls a JS function:

```
<body>
    <h1 onclick="scrape()"> Scrape! </h1>
    ...
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this JS script (main.js):

```
function scrape() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.wikipedia.org/", true)
    xhttp.send();
}
```

When I run the scrape() function it returns an error because of the Same Origin Policy.

After reading an SO post about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/35553666#35553666) I'm quite confused...

I read of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and this should make my site access to other sites' data, but I can't understand how to use it, could you please help me and tell me the way to make my function work?

Comment: This is not something that you need to implement. This is handled on backend so Wikipedia is allowing you to access this from a different origin. You can access this from no-browser environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set “Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *”?

You or any backend developer should set that header on the server-side if the requirement is to allow access from different origins (domains, subdomains, Etc.).  In this case, Wikipedia's backend is not setting that header for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, so how can i scrape datas from other web site?

Comment: @Flavié you can't, only the backend of the websites can allow the origin from where you are requesting.

Comment: So there are no ways i can acces to other web site's datas? I don't know,  maybe using a third party program?

Comment: Not with javascript.

Comment: @Flavié like I said, the backend-side must set that header, if not, is not possible. Unless you have access to the backend code.